# Foreign key between aggregate roots

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, domain-driven-design

I understand the concept of aggregate root and I know that one aggregate root must reference another by identity ( http://dddcommunity.org/wp-content/uploads/files/pdf_articles/Vernon_2011_2.pdf ) so what I don't get is how can I force Entity Framework to add a foreign key constraint between two aggregates?

Lets suppose I have a simplified domain:

```
public class AggregateOne{
    [Key]
    public Guid AggregateOneID{ get; private set;}
    public Guid AggregateTwoFK{get; private set;}
    /*Other Properties and methods*/
}

public class AggregateTwo{
    [Key]
    public Guid AggregateTwoID{get; private set;}
    /*Other Properties and methods*/
}
```

With this domain design, Entity Framework doesn't know that there is a relationship between AggregateOne and AggregateTwo and consequently there is no foreign key at the generated database.

Comment: My question would be whether you really need to care what your ORM thinks? :) --- the relationship is probably going to be enforced by your data store anyway.

Comment: As I am using CodeFirst, the database will be generated automatically based on my domain classes

Comment: Ah, I see.  Well, *that* could be a problem.  Admittedly I steer clear of ORMs so I am not au fait with all the ins-and-outs, but I've heard of this code-first thing :) --- I guess you will not be able to set up the referential integrity from code-first as you will not have the relationship set up.  You would probably need to define the referential integrity after the database is created; unless someone knows some nifty EF trick.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In DDD, EF doesn't exist. Domain relationships are not the same as database relationships. Don't try to mix EF with domain modeling, they don't work together. So in a nutshell, what you have there is not DDD, just plain old relational db masquerading as DDD. EF would be used by the Repositories and would care about persisting one Aggregate Root (AR).

Two ARs can work together, however you need to model the process according to the domain. EF is there to act as a db for the app, it's concerned with persistence issues and shouldn't care about the Domain. Persistence is all about storage and not about reflecting domain relationships (the EF entity is not the domain entity although they can have the same name and can look similar. The important detail is that both belong to different layers and handle different issues). The Domain repositories care only to persist the AR in a way that can be easily restored when it will change. If more AR need to be persisted together, embrace eventual consistency and learn how to use a service bus and sagas. It will greatly simplify your life (consider it a kind of implementation for the unit of work pattern).

For querying, the most clean and elegant way is to generate/update a read model suitable for the querying use cases and this is usually done  after a domain event tells the 'world' that something changed in the Domain.

Doing DDD right is not straightforward and it's very easy to fall into the trap, believing that you apply DDD when in fact you're just CRUD ing away, using DDD terminology. Also IMO CQRS is a must with DDD if you like an easy life.

Understand the domain without rushing it and being superficial, identify the bounded contexts, model the domain concepts and their use cases (very important!!!), define repository interfaces as you need them, and implement the repositories only when there's nothing else left to do (the real repos, in the mean time you can use fake ones like in memory repos - they're very fast to implement and your app being decoupled means it shouldn't care about how persistence is implemented, right?). I know it sounds weird, but this how you know you have a maintainable DDD app.

The point of implementing the repositories last is to really decouple the app from the persistence details and also to have defined the expectations(repository methods) the app has from persistence. Once defined, you can write tests :D then implement the repositories. The bonus is that you get to focus only on repo implementation is isolation and when the all tests pass, you know everything works as it should.

Comment: Then, you are suggesting that I need to maintain two models, one for my domain and one for Entity Framework? I am a bit confused because I had read the articles from Julie Lerman ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee532098.aspx?sdmr=JulieLerman&sdmi=authors ) and I thought that I only needed one model.

Comment: Personally when I've tried to do DDD with EF then what I've done is use the ORM for CRUD-only operations and made sure that my repositories both accept and return domain entities.  This cuts off a lot of the benefits of an ORM and if you're using Code First, probably means you have a lot of extra work to do maintaining 2 sets of entities.  Sadly I'm working on a project where we're using EF entities in the domain and it's not working.  Once the details of a RDBMS start to leak into your domain, you end up bending to the ORM, because it ain't going to do what you need.

Comment: YEs 2 models, because each models a different context. OF course that reading articles from the EF team tells you that you only need EF, but it's wrong. They're trying to push a product and they would love your app to be tightly coupled to EF. They don't care about YOUR app's design and maintainability. EF is a persistence detail, keep it there.

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips I think everyone who loves saying that using EF entities as base for domain entities is ok, will change their mind when they try to do proper DDD and realise that after a point they need to fight the ORM at every step. Using an ORM as the backbone of the business layer is so wrong and yet all the ORM author keep pushing that approach, as if their product will suddenly become useless if it isn't the center of the app.

Comment: @MikeSW couldn't agree with you more.  Examples of where using EF entities in your domain model goes wrong are numerous: private default constructors, large aggregates with a tree structure included within, storing enums as their string value, choosing not to have the id property publicly settable on your aggregate, choosing not to have certain DB-only fields publicly gettable or settable, using inheritance, using polymorphism... I could go on.  The work-arounds in EF (where they exist), are usually much worse than the problem.  Approaches like TPT and TPH make me want to cry.

Comment: Wow, you boys are killing me :) Maintaining two models implies a lot of work and a lot of mapping on the repositories. I'll wait a couple of days and if nobody gives me an alternative I'll mark your answer as right.

Comment: You have no idea how much 2 models are simplifying your life. ONe would handle busines rules and will model the domain, while other will be defined according to your queries needs. The latter will be generated from the former when saving or as a domain event handler. Focusing on one thing at the time, knowing you won't break things, is a HUGE advantage. However if you want to go the CRUD way, you can do it, but be honest about it and don't try to DDD-ize it

Comment: Why you think we need 2 models? In EShopOnContainers Ordering Microservice there is only one entity/aggregate model. It is POCO class with not reference to EF core. Whole configuration is in IEntityTypeConfiguration classes. There is also used hexagonal pattern

Answer (score 0):

Why should you have two complete different objects? Why not only expose your entities as domain objects through a domain interface? 
In this case there's no issue with having your entities also act as domain objects with their implementation details neatly hidden behind the interface.

Another point a neat way to represent aggregate roots with EF is to make sure the foreign key column also makes up the primary key of the dependant entity. In your case that would mean AggregateOneId and AggregateTwoFk together would form the composite primary key of AggregateOne. This will ensure that EF doesn't need a repository for removing instances off AggregateOne as long as it's removed from AggregateTwo's collection it will be properly marked for deletion from the databases (if you don't have key like this you need to remove it from AggregateOne set because EF would throw an exception not understanding the intent of the developer that AggregateOne should be deleted.